# October CMS authentication/register form

Tags: octobercms

I have installed October CMS, with template and October CMS User plugins (front end).

The signup/register account page has all the necessary fields but when I try to register new user and/or signup, no thing happens. The plugin are developed by October CMS and it should work.

The only part is I can come in think of, is the view file.

What I am doing wrong?

October CMS view file:

```
title = "Register"
url = "/register/"
layout = "default"
==

<div class="signin-screen">
<div class="signin-icon">
    <img src="{{ 'assets/images/logo.png'|theme }}" alt="Welcome to My Blog" />
    <h4>Sign up to <small>My Blog</small></h4>
</div>

<div class="signin-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control signin-field"
            value=""
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            id="signin-name" />
        <label class="signin-field-icon fui-user" for="signin-name"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control signin-field"
            value=""
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            id="signin-email" />
        <label class="signin-field-icon fui-mail" for="signin-email"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control signin-field"
            value=""
            placeholder="Password"
            id="signin-pass" />
        <label class="signin-field-icon fui-lock" for="signin-pass"></label>
    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="#">Register</a>

    <a class="signin-link" href="{{ 'samples/signin'|page }}">Already have an account?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is your template need extra lines of code.

Regarding to [User plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user#documentation) (Under documentation -> Account component) from OctroberCMS it is important to connect your template to user plugin by adding following lines to your template, it should do the trick:

```
title = "Register"
url = "/register/:code?"
layout = "default"
[account]
redirect = "home"
paramCode = "code"

==
{% component 'account' %}

<div class="signin-screen">
<div class="signin-icon">....etc
```